# Hibernate advanced in clause

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to do SQL in clause queries on DB_TABLE with hibernate. The in clause contains pairs of values. I got it working to query for (tid, mid) pair with the help of a component mapping see below.

I now need to additionally do an in clause query for another pair example (tid, organisation). How do I do this?

Target SQL Query

```
select * from DB_TABLE where ( c_tid, c_mid ) in ( ('t1', 'm1'), etc. )
```

Java query code

```
function List<DBTable> getDBTableList( List<TidMidId> tidMidList ) {
  Criterion crit = Restrictions.in( "tidMidId", tidMidList.toArray() );
  // pom is hibernate wrapper
  return pom.getObjects( DBTable.class, crit );
}
```

Hibernate Mapping:

```
<class name="com.DBTable" table="DB_TABLE" >
    <id name="id" type="long" column="K_ID">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">DB_TABLE$SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>

    <component name="tidMidId" class="com.TidMidId">
        <property name="tid" type="string" column="C_TID"/>
        <property name="mid" type="string" column="C_MID"/>
    </component>
    <property name="organisation" type="string" column="C_ORGANISATION"/>
    <property name="createTimestamp" type="timestamp" column="D_CREATE_TIMESTAMP"/>
    <property name="modTimestamp" type="timestamp" column="D_MOD_TIMESTAMP"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use HQL? Let Hibernate take care of SQL:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("FROM com.DBTable x WHERE x.tidMidId.tid = ? AND x.tidMidId.mid = ?");
q.setString(0, "t1");
q.setString(1, "m1");
return (List<com.DBTable>) q.list();
```

Adding more parameters is as easy as:

```
q = ".... AND x.organisation = ?");
q.setString(3, "someOrganization");
```

Comment: great answer, but while following the same aproach hibernate is generating 4 inner join instead 2. Can please see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613881/hibernate-query-gnerating-4-inner-join-where-i-specified-only-2-join-in-query